# distinguishing different types of keys in my keystore

Tags: java, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I have a problem.
  I load all the keys from my Windows-My key store, some of them are from the computer and others are from the smart card. There are Certificates(aliases) containing keys with different capabilities. Some can only encipher data or encipher secret keys, but I am interested in filtering out only the ones that can create digital signatures and verify digital signatures for non-repudiation. 
  What field from the certificate chain of a certain certificate will tell me that, or what would be the  way to get that information and get only the certificates with the attributes that I am looking for?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each certificate has a KeyUsage and ExtendedKeyUsage values. There are special key usages for encryption, signature etc, web server authentication etc.

Comment: how do i retrieve those values? when i load the cert like: Certificate certificate = ks.getCertificate(aliass); i don't get .getKeyUsage(); have to be dealning with X509Certificates for that? @nadir

Comment: when i cast it to X509 and use getKeyUsage().toString(); i get something like this: Z@77ef6359

Comment: Take a look at the portecle project, it's a nice tool that shows key usages and extended key usages. You could check how they take this info by looking at their sources on sourceforge http://sourceforge.net/p/portecle/code/ci/master/tree/

Answer (score 0):

As @Nadir said, there is a `KeyUsage` and optionally `ExtendedKeyUsage` in the certificate structure, you can check this at [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) where `KeyUsage` ASN1 format is defined as follows:

```
KeyUsage ::= BIT STRING {
     digitalSignature        (0),
     nonRepudiation          (1),  -- recent editions of X.509 have
                                -- renamed this bit to contentCommitment
     keyEncipherment         (2),
     dataEncipherment        (3),
     keyAgreement            (4),
     keyCertSign             (5),
     cRLSign                 (6),
     encipherOnly            (7),
     decipherOnly            (8) }
```

and `ExtendedKeyUsage` is defined as `SEQUENCE` of [Object identifiers OIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier):

```
ExtKeyUsageSyntax ::= SEQUENCE SIZE (1..MAX) OF KeyPurposeId
KeyPurposeId ::= OBJECT IDENTIFIER
```

where possible OIDs are:

```
id-kp-serverAuth             OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 1 }
id-kp-clientAuth             OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 2 }
id-kp-codeSigning            OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 3 }
id-kp-emailProtection        OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 4 }
id-kp-timeStamping           OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 8 }
id-kp-OCSPSigning            OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= { id-kp 9 }
```

As you ask to check which private key related to this certificate are issued to perform digital-signatures through java you can use the class [`java.security.cert.X509Certificate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html):

```
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

KeyStore ks = ...;
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
boolean[] keyUsage = certificate.getKeyUsage();
// keyUsage[0] --> digitalSignature
// keyUsage[1] --> non repudiation
if(keyUsage[0] || keyUsage[1]){
   // certificate is issued to perform signature
}
```

Optionally if you need it, you can also access the `ExtendedKeyUsage` with the same class:

```
X509Certificate certificate =...;
certificate .getExtendedKeyUsage();
```

Hope this helps,